# Decomposition of $G$-harmonic polynomials

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, invariant-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H_G$ denote the $G$-harmonic polynomials. What is the structure of $H_G$ as a $G$-module? Is it isomorphic to the regular representation?

Answer (score 2):

In fact $H_G$ is isomorphic to the regular representation if and only if G is generated by (pseudo)-reflections.  This is a theorem of Steinberg.  A good reference for this is the manuscript "Orbit Harmonics and Graded Representations" by Haiman and Garsia.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is a finite reflection group, this is correct.